# Divide by zero runtime error while using a loop

Tags: python, numpy, runtime

I had gotten a divide by zero runtime error while using a loop and I do not know why. Don't worry, the code is unfinished yet. I am trying to convert an array using the ulj function if you can help. Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
def ulj(x,epsilon = 4*(10**-4),sigma=6):
"""Compute Lennard-Jones potential as a function of inter-atomic distance"""
return epsilon*((((sigma)/(x))**12)-((((sigma)/(x))**6)))




 positions=np.array([0., 7.0,5,6,2,6,2,2,4,3]) # Initial position of the two objects (in atomic            units)

i = 0

x1 = []
x2 = []
while i <(len(positions)):
    x1.append(ulj(positions[i]))

print(x1)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please also format your code/indentation correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Change while loop with below code snippet

```
while i <(len(positions)):
    print(positions[i])
    x1.append(ulj(positions[i]))
    i = i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

While Mohit Sharma is correct, you should be incrementing `i` inside of the loop (to avoid an infinite loop), the answer to why a divide by zero error is happening is the following.

When `i == 0`, `positions[i] == 0`.

Therefore, `ulj(positions[i])` is `ulj(0)`.

This means that inside your function, `x == 0`, and `sigma/x` will be raise a divide by zero exception.